# Create an array with varying increment in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python I know how to create an array starting at some value a, incrementing each component thereon by some m until it reaches some value b:

`array = numpy.arange(a, b, m)`

However, what if I want m to change? Specifically, I want the array
1,2,...9,10,20,...90,100,200,...900,1000..

So increasing my increment by a factor of 10 every ten components. What would be the easiest way to achieve this? If I had to I could use loops and do this 'manually' but is there a nicer way?

Comment: Since you don't know a "nicer way" and the "manual" code is pretty short and clear, what is wrong with "manually"?

Comment: For a generic case, use the linked dup. For this special case : `(10**np.arange(4)[:,None]*np.arange(1,10)).ravel()`.

Comment: can't answer as question was closed: here an idea: `import numpy as np; from itertools import chain; ar = np.fromiter(chain(*(range(10**n, 10*10**n, 10**n) for n in range(4))), dtype='int')`. this will create only your numpy array in memory and no other list.

Answer (score 6):

You could take advantage of numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to achieve this in a couple of lines. You can create one array that gives you 1-9, then multiply that with an array that gives you powers of ten. You then flatten the final array to give you the list you want.

```
>>> a = np.arange(1,10)
>>> b = 10**np.arange(4)
>>> (b[:, np.newaxis] * a).flatten()

array([   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   20,
     30,   40,   50,   60,   70,   80,   90,  100,  200,  300,  400,
    500,  600,  700,  800,  900, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000,
   7000, 8000, 9000])
```

Comment: Use `10**np.arange(4)` to create `b` maybe.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to read or pretty, but here is a one-liner:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [range(10**n, 10*10**n, 10**n) for n in range(4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an infinite generator:

```
def rudyard_steps(value=1, increment=1):
    while True:
        yield value
        value += increment
        if value % (10*increment) == 0:
            increment *= 10
```

Now to get the first 500 or so,

```
from itertools import islice
print(list(islice(rudyard_steps(), 500)))
```